# ADD combination constraint into a dabase table

Tags: sql, constraints, unique

I want to make a combination of columns in a table unique which they can not have any duplicates value.

For example, I have a table of `Person` which contain a name, age, address and phone_number.

I want that the combination of `(name, age, phone_number)` must be unique.

The table person contain this data:

```
"Name1"|22|"adresse1"|000000
```

So the combination (''Name1''  and 22 and 000000) it has to be unique but if only one of them changed for example ("name2",22,000000) it will be permitted to insert data to the table.

How can I manage that with SQL please?

Comment: **combination** - not "combinisation" .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a column or combination of columns to be unique, you can implement a unique constraint or index (they are functionally equivalent for this purpose):

```
create unique index unq_t_col1_col2_col3 on t(col1, col2, col3);
```

And for a constraint:

```
alter table t add constraint unq_t_col1_col2_col3
    unique (col1, col2, col3);
```

Any attempt to insert values into the columns that already exists will result in an error, as will any attempt to update the columns with values in a different row.

Comment: Thank you i'll test it, but i wanna know what's the difference between these two instructions?

Comment: @GhàithMn . . . There is no functional difference.  Naming the constraint means that error messages involving the constraint return the constraint name.